# SPGridView extend filter

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, spgridview

I'm working on a SharePoint Foundation. Since SPF doesn't provide Content Query Web Part, I'm  trying to create a search webpart.

[image: Search webpart]

In the results gridview there is a column that will show the content type of an item. Is it possible for me to extend the filter to show all the fields define in a content type on mouse over. So that when the user mouse over on the content type and click on on of the displayed field, I will execute another search query with the property filter technique 
e.g. Title:"my resume"

Really appreciate any helps and suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need for sure to built it yourself by attempting to attach your own coding to it.

This articles explains the mechanism triggering the filter behaviour http://ketulpatel.wordpress.com/2008/05/30/custom-filters-in-spgridview/, but as of yet (except probably when customizing the XSLTViewWebPart - which does not apply here) I haven't seen a hookup as you mentioned.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending your SPGridView in [the manner shown on this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35536/Creation-of-a-SPGridview-Webpart-having-Pagination), you may have luck created a DataSource populated with the Content Types which you can query from the SharePoint API.

Comment: thanks for the effort, really appreciate it. I've came across that article before. It does not provide an hints on how to extend the filtering part.